# Mongodb Gridfs Reduce image size

Tags: mongodb, gridfs, node-mongodb-native

I am working on a facebook like application using node.js and mongodb. I have been able to successfully upload image files to GridFS and retrieve them back using the awesome examples of the node-mongodb-native driver wiki. The maximum use of images will be as thumbnails, so I understand from various SO posts that keeping both a big size version and a small size version will be the fastest solution.

So my question is how do a create various sized copies of the same image. A number of such questions have been asked on SO like [MongoDB GridFS store multiple sizes of image or use on the fly resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516045/mongodb-gridfs-store-multiple-sizes-of-image-or-use-on-the-fly-resizing) But none really answers HOW to  change the size.

In the mongo shell, I can see in the fs.chunks collection the binary data of the original image, surely there MUST be some way to manipulate this binary data to get the smaller sized image which I can then save as a separate GridFS chunk OR some other way. Please help , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the size of an image, you have to scale it before you save it to GridFS. GridFS has nothing to do with the process of scaling the image.

However, if I remember correctly, you can make a data stream of GridFS binary data. [node-gd](https://github.com/taggon/node-gd) is a library for scaling images (among other things), and as far as I know it can handle streams.

If you can work with the uploaded files directly (before saving them to GridFS), [node-imagemagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick) provides a very simple resize function:

```
/* with express */
app.post('/image', function(req, res) {
    file = req.files[0];
    (require 'imagemagick')
        .resize({
            srcPath: file.path,
            dstPath: file.path + '-smaller.png',
            width: 50}, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        /* You now have two files: file.path is the original, file.path + '-smaller.png' is the thumbnail. */
    });
});
```

Comment: hi lambda, thanks for the quick reply. it seems that the resize is working, but when i am using the file.path + 'smaller.png' for the GridFS part it says: TypeError: Bad argument at Object.fstat
I am saying  that resize is working because in my code, the GridFS part for the original image is also after this  resize and it goes through without any problem with file.path

Comment: Perhaps the variable is overridden or something, you should probably store `file.path + '-smaller.png'` into a seperate variable. I don't know your code or how GridFS handles this, perhaps you should open a different question with your code, asking for the error.